# react-big-calendar navigate to specific day / month

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, react-big-calendar

I'm using BigCalendar [react-big-calendar](https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar), and I'm trying to find an example on how to navigate to specific day / month when defaultDate state value changes.

```
<BigCalendar
        events={props.events}
        defaultDate={this.state.selectedDay}
/>
```

I’m wondering if BigCalendar calendar supports navigating into a specific day / month, the documentation include [onNavigate](http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-onNavigate) prop, but I haven't been able make it work.

```
    <BigCalendar
      selectable
      events={events}
      defaultView='week'
      defaultDate={this.state.selectedDay}
      onNavigate={() => { this.state.selectedDay }}
    />
```

Thanks

Comment: put the console i think it will pass the date selected in callback method, and you need to set that date in defaultDate, try this: `onNavigate={(a,b,c) => { console.log(a,b,c); this.steState(selectedDay: /*date value*/) }}` check the console value of a b c, any one of them should be the selected date.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you don't want to use `defaultDate` in this case since you are *controlling* the value yourself

```
<BigCalendar
  selectable
  events={events}
  defaultView='week'
  date={this.state.selectedDay}
  onNavigate={date => {
    this.setState({ selectedDate: date });
  }}
/>
```

that will tell teh calendar, to always use the date you tell it to.

Comment: @monastic-panic is there a way to do this from within a custom toolbar component?

Comment: I think I tried this way of setting `date` but it disabled the nav (next buttons) for some reason

Answer (score 3):

I tried using the chosen answer to this question where it says to update the `date` property. But when it navigated to the date I was not able to use the navigation button.

For example when I clicked the next button nothing happened.

So what I did was, I used `onNavigate` .The first provided argument of that method is the date object. When I clicked the button the `onNavigate` was triggered and I was able to update the date and have the button work.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
<Calendar
    date={date}
    onChange={onDateChange}
    onNavigate={date => {
      setDate(date);
    }}
    value={date}
    showNeighboringMonth={false}
    selectRange={true}
    localizer={localizer}
    events={props.events}
    startAccessor='start'
    endAccessor='end'
    style={{ height: 600 }}
    defaultView={props.defaultView}
    components={{ event: EventComponent }}
  />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).